Kinesis Lambda Event Source Mapping Concurrent Invocation
I am running a Lambda function to read data from a Kinesis data stream and perform some processing. The stream has 4 shards and 10 data records. Shard01 has 1 record, Shard02 has no records, Shard03 has 4 records, and Shard04 has 5 records.
As per my understanding, when we set up an event source mapping, Lambda processes the data from the stream with concurrent execution, where each shard gets its own Lambda invocation. This should mean that in my case, there would be 4 parallel Lambda invocations, resulting in 4 separate log streams.
However, when I check the logs in CloudWatch, I see only 1 log stream, and the same Lambda function seems to be invoked multiple times to process data from each shard.
Event source mapping has a Batch size of 4, Batch window of 10 and Starting position as TRIM_HORIZON.
Here is my lambda code:
import json
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['Records']:

        partition_key = record['kinesis']['partitionKey']
        decoded_data = base64.b64decode(record["kinesis"]["data"]).decode("utf-8")
        decoded_data_json = json.loads(decoded_data)
        print(partition_key)

And here is the log output:
INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.12.v28 Runtime Version ARN: 
START RequestId: 9dc66a89-2481-4a31-a257-200d7b477efe Version: $LATEST
Log stream name= 2024/07/02/[$LATEST]aea74027ea7d47fabe8b1d5ab204cb8f  Request Id= 9dc66a89-2481-4a31-a257-200d7b477efe
ID-00000000000000
ID-00000000000001
ID-00000000000002
ID-00000000000003
ID-00000000000005
END RequestId: 9dc66a89-2481-4a31-a257-200d7b477efe
REPORT RequestId: 9dc66a89-2481-4a31-a257-200d7b477efe  Duration: 6.19 ms   Billed Duration: 7 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  Init Duration: 485.97 ms    
START RequestId: 47a2c120-2b7f-46f6-8307-24da9c1ec12e Version: $LATEST
Log stream name= 2024/07/02/[$LATEST]aea74027ea7d47fabe8b1d5ab204cb8f  Request Id= 47a2c120-2b7f-46f6-8307-24da9c1ec12e
ID-00000000000009
END RequestId: 47a2c120-2b7f-46f6-8307-24da9c1ec12e
REPORT RequestId: 47a2c120-2b7f-46f6-8307-24da9c1ec12e  Duration: 1.61 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  
START RequestId: f192b628-7284-4c7e-badc-b9ba7c498b54 Version: $LATEST
Log stream name= 2024/07/02/[$LATEST]aea74027ea7d47fabe8b1d5ab204cb8f  Request Id= f192b628-7284-4c7e-badc-b9ba7c498b54
ID-00000000000004
ID-00000000000006
ID-00000000000007
ID-00000000000008
END RequestId: f192b628-7284-4c7e-badc-b9ba7c498b54
REPORT RequestId: f192b628-7284-4c7e-badc-b9ba7c498b54  Duration: 5.11 ms   Billed Duration: 6 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  

I ran it 2 times again. First time 3 different log streams are generated to process each shard and the other time only 1 log stream is generated.
Can someone please explain the reason behind this behavior? Is there something wrong with my understanding?
